# Why is the upload file controller not hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

I'm creating an upload webpage. I set the controler's opacity=0 and set it's position to be abosolute and on top of an image. So that users won't see the ugly controler, but click the controler when they click the image.

Everything works fine, however, when and only when the upload succeeds message pop out, the ugly controler shows.And when you click OK, the controler dispears with the pop out message. What more weird is, it doesn't show every time. But it does shows some time like once every two counts. Any idea?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var left = $('#browseButton').offset().left;
    var top = $('#browseButton').offset().top;
    $("[id$='File1']").css('left', left);
    $("[id$='File1']").css('top', top);
    $("[id$='File1']").css('position', 'absolute');
    $("[id$='File1']").css('z-index', '999');
});


<div align="center">Please choose attachment to upload
    <input id="Text1" type="text" style="width: 400px" /><img src="../images/browse.jpg" id="browseButton" style="cursor:pointer;" width="24px" height="24px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/upload-eng.gif" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />
<input type=file id="File1" name=File1 runat="server" onchange="Text1.value=this.value" style="filter:alpha(opacity=0);width:24px;height:24px;" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is happening, but you could additionally set the `border:none` and `background-color:transparent` on the upload controller so that even if it does randomly show up, there's nothing to see.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it doesn't work. You still could say a gray button there.

Comment: oh of course, sorry. didn't realize the button was showing up as well. Does it appear any time any alert shows up on the page, or just after youv'e finished uploading?

Comment: I just tested several times. Again, it doesn't show every time. But when it shows, no matter it finishes upload or not. It appears when a javascript message shows up.

Comment: can you try showing a javascript alert after the page loads, to see if it's being caused by the alert being shown?

Comment: OK, I added a javascript alert after the page loads to see what happened. I refreshed the page 10 times, the button appeared 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you cant use `display:none` on the upload button?

Also just a recommendation, but file upload tools have been written before and maybe this one can be helpful ([Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)). It has many features, including multi-file uploading using CTRL + clicking all files and queuing the files being uploaded.